# How can one rename a project in sublime text editor 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I would like to rename my project in sublime IDE. How do I do that?

I don't want to change the name of the folder, just project name.

Hope I'm clear.

Comment: For using Sublime as an IDE, you should read chromiun article about it so you can give yourself an Idea of it.
If I understand what you want to do and you really created a project, you should edit the configuration JSON file: https://www.chromium.org/developers/sublime-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the project name that appears in the window title bar.

The project name is based on the `.sublime-project` file's basename.

So for example when the project file name is `Awesome Project Name.sublime-project` then the project name is "Awesome Project Name".

`Menu > Project > Save Project As...`

Comment: Works like a charm. Just save using the desired project name and delete the old one.

Answer (score 4):

Install plugin for Sublime Text 3 [Project​Manager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ProjectManager)
and you have option to rename project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To rename an existing project in Sublime:

1. open the project you want to rename via `Open Project` or `Switch Project`.
2. use `Project > Save Project As...` to save the project with the new name.

New `<name>.sublime-project` and `<name>.sublime-workspace` files will be created and you will be switched into the new project. Because you are already in a project all of the settings from the previous project will be copied into the new `.sublime-project` file.

After you have created the new project you can delete the `<name>.sublime-project/workspace` files for the original project.

The old project name may still show up in the quick switcher or `Project > Open Recent`, but you can solve that with `Remove Deleted` in the `Open Recent` menu.